# JavaFX WebView - parse HTML string and update WebView

Tags: java, webview, javafx, html-parsing, domdocument

I'd like to parse a HTML code and add it to a div.

The code is as shown below:

```
HTMLElement targetDiv = (HTMLElement) WebMisc.getHTMLElement(webViewPanel.getWebEngine(), "targetDiv");
Document contentDocument = XMLMisc.getDocument(contentString);
Element documentElement = contentDocument.getDocumentElement();
if(documentElement != null){
    NodeList list = documentElement.getChildNodes();
    if(list != null && list.getLength() > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++){
            try{    
                targetDiv.appendChild(list.item(i));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(Misc.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XMLMisc.java

```
public static Document getDocument(final String xml) throws Exception{
    if(Misc.stringHasContent(xml)){
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        Document document = builder.parse(inputSource);
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        return document;
    }
    return null;
}
```

WebMisc.java

```
public static Element getHTMLElement(WebEngine webEngine, final String elementID){
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="code">
    if(webEngine != null && Misc.stringHasContent(elementID)){
        webEngine.getDocument().normalize();
        return webEngine.getDocument().getElementById(elementID);
    }
    return null;
    //</editor-fold>
}
```

However, the above codes will cause the following Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.webkit.dom.NodeImpl
```

How do I fix this?

targetDiv is just a HTMLElement with the corresponding code in the HTML file

```
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```

The following is the StackTrace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.webkit.dom.NodeImpl
com.sun.webkit.dom.NodeImpl.getPeer(NodeImpl.java:200)
com.sun.webkit.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(NodeImpl.java:369)
browser.JavaFXApp$3$2.run(JavaFXApp.java:527) //my application
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: The line "targetDiv.appendChild(list.item(i));" is throwing the Exception.

Comment: Can you show the whole stack trace? And perhaps also what `targetDiv` is?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. It seems WebEngine's Document implementation cannot import nodes from other Document implementations.

Comment: I've just opened an issue: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40127